# Using JavaScript in WordPress page to call for server data using AJAX

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, javascript

I am developing a site on WordPress that uses the JavaScript-based plotting library, [Plotly](https://plot.ly/javascript/line-and-scatter/), to plot data retrieved from a data server. I need the user to be able to enter text into a text field that will update the graph as the user types. I want the site to work similar to this [w3schools example](https://w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp).

**What I have so far:**

- I can run JavaScript in my page using this plugin, [Scripts and Styles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/scripts-n-styles/).
- I can run the Ploty graph on the page using the Scripts and Styles plugin using this code:

  ```
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
  <script>
      TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
      Plotly.plot( TESTER, [{
          x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16] }], {
     margin: { t: 0 } } );
  </script>
  </body>
  ```

**What I'm missing:**

- I don't know how to make JavaScript send an AJAX to a custom PHP plugin to retrieve data to post back to the Plotly graph.

Moral of the story, I need to be able to update a Plotly graph on a WordPress site.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of good resources out there to help you build a plugin, but the one I recommend most is the WordPress Plugin Developer Handbook, especially the [section on Ajax](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/). You will still need to figure out the functionality needed for the Plotly data, but that should get you in the right direction.